# Prove a bounded set with the betweenness property is an interval

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> If $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, $S$ is bounded above and not bounded below, and $S$ has the betweenness property, show that either $S = (-\infty, x)$ or $S = (-\infty, x]$ for some $x$.
>
> ($S \subset \mathbb{R}$ has the betweenness property if whenever $a, b \in S$ and $a < c < b$, then $c \in S$.)

These are one of those proofs where it seems like both the "if" and "then" parts seem the same thing to me. Maybe it is obvious, but I just can't put the proof in words. Here is my feeble attempt at a "proof":

So if $S$ is bounded above, it has a least upper bound since it's a subset of a complete ordered field. Let $x$ be the least upper bound. Then $x \geq y$, $\forall y \in S$. If $x \in S$, then we have that $(-\infty, x]$ since $x$ is the least upper bound for $S$. If not, then by the betweenness property there exists $z, y \in S$ such that $z > x > y$, which contradicts that $x$ is the least upper bound of $S$. If $x \not\in S$, then we have $(-\infty, x)$ because if we have $z, y \in S$ such that $z > w > y$, then $w \in S$ but $w$ is not the least upper bound, and neither is $z$. So if $x > z$ $\forall z \in S$, then we have $(-\infty, x)$.

I feel like this doesn't make any sense when I read it, but I don't know what else to say but I have to write something.

Comment: By the way the "betweenness property" is usually called [convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of finding the least upper bound and breaking into cases depending on whether $x\in S$ is correct, but you haven't applied the betweenness property correctly, and you haven't applied the unbounded below property at all (note that intervals of the form $[a,x]$ or variants open at one or both ends satisfy all the properties except being unbounded below).

**Lemma:** If $x\in S$, then $(-\infty,x]\subseteq S$.

*Proof*: If $y\le x$, then either $y=x$ (so $y\in S$) or $y<x$. Since $S$ is unbounded below there is a $z<y$ in $S$, and then by the betweenness property, $x,z\in S$ and $z<y<x$ implies $y\in S$.

Now since $S$ is bounded above, there is a least upper bound $x$, and since this is an upper bound $S\subseteq(-\infty,x]$, so if $x\in S$ we get $S=(-\infty,x]$ by the Lemma. Otherwise, $S\subseteq(-\infty,x)$, and for any $y<x$ there is a $z<y$ in $S$, and so by the Lemma $y\in (-\infty,z]\subseteq S$. Thus $(-\infty,x)\subseteq S$ and hence $S=(-\infty,x)$.

Comment: Remark: My answer differs slightly from William Stagner's answer in not using countable choice.

Comment: One doesn't need countable choice. In my proof, you can take $y_n = \sup(S) - n$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner I think you would need a bit more for that; I assumed you wanted $y_n\in S$, which would need countable choice, but if not, then the statement doesn't exactly follow from what you proved in the previous statement.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$
[a,b] = \{x\in \mathbb R \mid a \leq x \leq b\}.
$$
So since $S$ has the betweenness property, if $a,b \in S$ $(a < b)$, then $[a,b] \subset S$.
Take any sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, where $y_n \leq \sup(S)$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n = -\infty$. Then
$$
S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [y_n, \sup(S)] = (-\infty, \sup(S)],
$$
if $\sup(S) \in S$, and similarly with a half-open interval if $\sup(S) \notin S$.